# General Non-Uniform Berry-Essen

Tags: convergence, polynomial, bounds

Let $f_n(x)$ by the probability distribution function of a  continuous r.v. $X_n$. $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$, i.e. $|P(X_n < x) - P(X < x)| \rightarrow 0$. On the top of that, $E[|X_n|^p]$ converges to the $k$th moment of $X$, i.e. $\int |x|^p (f_n(x) - f(x))dx \rightarrow 0$.

With these ingredients, I would like to prove a non-uniform bound of the type:

$$(1 + |x|^p)|f_n(x) - f(x)| = o(1)$$